# MySQL load data insert, split values to multiple rows

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

Using the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

num column Store every 6 digits

How can I parameterize the load command to iterate through the array?

Mysql version 8.0.23

In File text

```
id length 1,
cnt length 2,
num length 500
--------------------
1 3AB1001AB1002AB1003
```

table A

| id | cnt | num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | AB1001AB1002AB1003 |

i want output like this table

table B

| id | cnt | num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | AB1001 |
| 1 | 3 | AB1002 |
| 1 | 3 | AB1003 |

Comment: What are the contents of the file you are reading? Please [edit] your question to add them in. Also add which version of MySQL you are using.

Comment: We've added what you mentioned

Comment: *split values to multiple rows* Noway in LOAD DATA. Load into temptable then parse loaded data into main table.

Comment: There is no array or json here. You need to splot a string into substrings. A yeah, this cannot be done in one step in load data infile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to test this table:

```
create table mytable (
  id int,
  cnt int,
  num varchar(500)
);
```

I put the line of text you show into a file `p.csv`:

```
1 3AB1001AB1002AB1003
```

I ran the mysql client with the option to enable local data loading:

```
$ mysql --local-data
```

Then I loaded the data file this way:

```
mysql> load data local infile 'p.csv' into table mytable (@temp)
set id = substr(@temp, 1, 1),
    cnt = substr(@temp, 2, 2),
    num = substr(@temp, 3);
```

It worked!

```
mysql> select * from mytable;
+------+------+---------------------+
| id   | cnt  | num                 |
+------+------+---------------------+
|    1 |    3 | 3AB1001AB1002AB1003 |
+------+------+---------------------+
```

Read more about the LOAD DATA INFILE statement here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

And read about the SUBSTR() function here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger to split a row from table 'a' into 3 rows for 'b'.
The trigger is following:

```
`CREATE TRIGGER triger1 AFTER INSERT ON a FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET @i = 0;
REPEAT
SET @part = SUBSTRING(NEW.num, 1 + @i*6, 6);
INSERT INTO b VALUE(NEW.id, NEW.cnt, @part);
SET @i = @i + 1;
UNTIL @i = NEW.cnt
END REPEAT;
END;`
```

Before insert data using the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, you have to create a trigger on table 'a'.
Regards.

Comment: When a new row inserted into table `a` NEW.num value is split with NEW.cnt rows into `b`.